# How to iterate a JSON ARRAY with Laravel Blade?

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to iterate through the values ​​of a **JSON ARRAY** with no success. When the file has a single value, I loop through it with no problem.

**Controller**

```
$data = '[{
        "T": {
            "HD": {
                "HD01": "1",
                "HD02": "06033942",
                "HD03": "3736803"
                }
            }
         }]';
             
      $data = json_decode($data);
      return view('dashboard.book.index', ['data' => $data[0]]);
```

**Blade**

```
<tbody>
        @foreach($data as $item)
            <tr>
                 @foreach($item->HD as $title)
                <td>{{ $title }}</td>
                 @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
<tbody>
```

**Result**

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJuHY.jpg)

But when it starts to have more than one value, I can't get the same results:

**Controller**

```
$data = '[{
        "T": {
            "HD": {
                "HD01": "1",
                "HD02": "06033942",
                "HD03": "3736803"
                }
            }
        },
        {
        "T": {
            "HD": {
                "HD01": "2",
                "HD02": "06035419",
                "HD03": "4736521"
                }
            }
        }]';

$data = json_decode($data);
return view('dashboard.book.index', ['data' => $data]);
```

**Result**

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dEki.jpg)

With **$data[0]** I get the values ​​individually, but when I want to send the whole array I get errors.

How can I modify my code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to convert the `JSON` to an associative array and then to a Laravel [`collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections) in order to use some of the [helper methods](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods) available.

So for example:

```
return view('dashboard.book.index', [
    'data' => collect(json_decode($data, true))->flatten(2)
]);
```

Then in your blade view file:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach ($data->first() as $key => $value)
            <th>{{ $key }}</th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    @foreach ($data as $items)
        <tr>
            @foreach ($items as $key => $value)
                <td>{{ $value }}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

###### Update

If you want to remove certain keys from the `$data` variable, you could do the following:

```
$keysToRemove = ['HD02', 'HD06'];

$data = collect(json_decode($data, true))
    ->flatten(2)
    ->map(function ($array, $key) use ($keysToRemove) {
        foreach ($keysToRemove as $key) {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $array;
});

return view('dashboard.book.index', [
    'data' => $data
]);
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I'll put you as the correct answer... I only have one more question: how do I have control over the <th> to obtain the individual values?... For example, if I want to obtain 'HD01' and 'HD08', and I want to remove 'HD06 '....

Comment: @AdolfiTéllez Have a look at my update which I think answers your second question about removing unwanted elements based on the `array` `key`.

Comment: Dude, you're a genius... You have my respect... I really appreciate it...

Answer (score 0):

On your controller:

```
  $data = json_decode($data, true);
```

The second parameter  When true, returned objects will be converted into
associative arrays.