# How to get the individual values ​of a JSON ARRAY?

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade

Given the Example Json:

**Controller**

```
$json = '[{
"T": {
    "HD": {
        "HD01": "1",
        "HD06": "20201006033942",
        "HD08": "3736803"
        }
    }
},
{
"T": {
    "HD": {
        "HD01": "2",
        "HD06": "20201006035419",
        "HD08": "7523658"
        }
    }
}]';

       $json = json_decode($data, true);

        $details = collect($json)->map(function ($value){
             return $value["T"]["HD"];
        });

        return view('dashboard.book.index', [
           'data' => $details
        ]);
```

How can I get the value of 'HD01' with the following path?
I get the listed values ​​and I can hide them with code in the controller, but the idea is to be able to show it by accessing the element directly.

**Blade**

```
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td> HD01</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($data as $items)
            <tr>
                @foreach ($items as $key => $value)
                <td>{{ $value }}</td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
```

I have tried to access as follows, but I get the error:
**Undefined array key "HD01"**

```
<table class="table">
       <tr>
           <td> HD01</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($data as $items)
         <tr>
          <td>{{ $items['HD01'] }}</td>
       </tr>
      @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish. Are you just wanting to filter just the `HD01` elements in your controller?

Comment: I want to display items based on their name: Example:
<td>{{ $value->HD01 }}</td>
<td>{{ $value->HD02 }}</td>

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is an [`associative array`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/associative-arrays-in-php/) not an [`object`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-objects) so you can't access other data of the `data` variable using the object operator (`->`). Instead, you need to access data using square brackets and a key (e.g. `$indexedArray[0]`, `$associativeArray['key']`).

The structure of `$data` when it is in your blade view looks like the following:

```
[
    0 => [
        "HD01": "1",
        "HD06": "20201006033942",
        "HD08": "3736803"
    ],
    1 => [
        "HD01": "2",
        "HD06": "20201006035419",
        "HD08": "7523658"
    ]
]
```

Your first `@foreach` is iterating (looping) over the outer indexed array and the second `@foreach` is iterating over the inner associative array.

In order to access specific elements via their key, you would need to modify your code slightly:

```
@foreach ($data as $items)
    {{ $items['HD01'] }}
    {{ $items['HD06'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I have tried it that way and get the error:
'Undefined array key "HD01"'

Comment: @AdolfiTéllez How are you trying to access it? Can you update your question accordingly?

Comment: I have updated it now

Comment: @AdolfiTéllez I think you need to check that the structure of `$data` is as you expect.